# C: Trouble with operators and results of function

Tags: c

I am a college student who is taking his first programming class, in the process of studying a past exam I found this question:

give the following values of the print function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
float x;
int a = 5, b = 0;
x = a&b ? 2/8.f*5+b++ : a|b
printf("%f\n", x);

}
```

The printf displays 5.000 after running.  What is tripping me up is the ?: operator.  As I understand it, it works almost like an if, else statement, where if (condition) is true, then x, if not true then y.  I don't understand the flow of the function.

is it saying that because the a&b yields 0 that it is not true, therefore x = a|b which after the operator runs yields decimal value 5?

Comment: look up "ternary operator"

Comment: Looks like you understand this just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is exactly correct. The operator is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C). In this case, the code evaluates `a&b` to be `0` or false, which causes it to use the value after the `:`, or `a|b`, which is `5`. If, instead, `b` were to equal `1` for example, then `a&b` would evaluate to true, and `x` would equal the expression before the `:`, which evaluates to `2.25`.

Comment: Nitpick: It's actually called conditional operator and _is_ a ternary operator (C's only one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate the opposing example.  So the a&b only needs to evaluate to a whole number for the condition to be true? or specifically to 1?

Comment: @JohnX: Any number other than 0 is considered to be true in C. So `a&b` only needs to be non-zero for it to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

> is it saying that because the a&b yields 0 that it is not true, therefore x = a|b which after the operator runs yields decimal value 5?

Yup.

The expression parses out as follows:

```
(a & b) ? ((2 / 8.f) * 5 + (b++)) : (a | b)
```

`&` is the bitwise AND operator; it will perform an AND operation on each bit of the two operands.  Since `a` is 5 (`101`) and `b` is 0 (`000`), the result of `a&b` is `101 & 000 == 000`.

Since `a&b` evaluates to 0, the expression following the `?` is not evaluated; instead, `(a|b)` is evaluated.  `|` is the bitwise OR operator.  `101 | 000 == 101`, which is 5.

Hence your result.

Comment: Hey, can't upvote your answer but thanks a bunch for the clarification!  Glad to know I figured that thing out correctly haha.